# gcloud get-credentials requires edit permission even though I have credentials

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I used `gcloud auth login` to login on gcloud, when I try to run `get-credentials` I get a `requires edit permission`.  I ran `gcloud auth list` to make sure I a have credentials. Not sure how to fix this.
[image]

Comment: you ran this command gcloud config set account 'ACOUNT' ?

Comment: As said in the previous comment try running the set account 'ACCOUNT" command and see if it works.